# I would like to change table value using ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a select-option and i choose one,i wanna change tablo value from database.
In my View :

```
<select id="Room" >
    <option value="Joseph">Joseph Room</option>
    <option value="Macro">Macro Lounge</option>
</select>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Day</td>
        <?php
        foreach ($posts as $post)
        {
            echo "<td>{$post->seancehour}</td>";
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $post->seanceday; ?></td><td><?php echo $post->seancename; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I use ajax and want to change dynamiccally table value.My javascript is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#Room').change(function () {
            var room = document.getElementById("Room").value;
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {room: room},
                url: '<?php echo site_url('Homepage/index'); ?>',
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);//I dont know what has to be here.
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

In my Controller,I go mymodel and get database value.

```
public function index()
{
    $room = $this->input->post('room');

    if ($room == 'Macro')
    {
        $this->data['pasts'] = $this->SeanceModel->getMacro();
    }
    else
    {
        $this->data['posts'] = $this->SeanceModel->getJoseph();
    }
    $this->load->view('Homepage', $this->data);
}
```

For example when i open the page day=Sunday hour=12pm,if i change joseph or macro,this values must be change in the table.

Comment: Focus on the `//I dont know what has to be here.` That's where you'd take the result and populate your table accordingly. You'll probably want to use an id or class on the table so that you can select it or maybe even on the specific column. Your call to Homepage/index probably needs to return json data.

Comment: Where is update statement ??

Comment: I update data in controller but can't see dynamically in View. $post-seanceday must be change i change select-option tag. @devpro

Comment: dataType :"html", use in ajax param

Comment: it is the same.I called Homepage/index all times but it doesn't update.@devpro